# What does double ampersand do in this program?

Tags: c, process, fork, ampersand

I am learning how to create processes by using fork, and I am confused in the following. This is the code:

```
int main() {
    int ret = fork();
    // printf("%d\n", ret);
    ret = ret && fork(); /* Here is where I am confused*/
    // print("ret: %d\n", ret);
    if(ret == 0) {
        fork();
    }
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 1;
}
```

So, what is the use of double ampersand exactly doing?
I ran the program with a "printf" to know what was exactly the values, but it became more confusing because the output in the first "printf" is 0 and the second "printf" is "1". So I am not quite sure what is double ampersand doing.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: It is a boolean operator... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations Also, it is very... interesting, why there is a `return 1` at the end. This is nonsense.

Comment: What you need is a tutorial covering the basics of C.

Comment: sloppy code is indeed confusing

Comment: @dandan78 ...... read my comment

Comment: @oscarin In that case, you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Gandaro read my comment below NickDandoulakis!!

Comment: @NickDandoulakis read my comment below yours!!!

Comment: @Oscarin Why are you shouting at us? This is inpolite. You should use less exclamation marks and you should have read my comment completely: I said: "It is a boolean operator."

Comment: @Gandaro Impolite?? Did you see what you posted?? Can I asked you why do you criticize this code? What do you mean that "This is nonsense." or why "why there is a return 1 at the end."? I also asked what does this double ampersand DO in this program? I did not asked What IS double ampersand? Can you explain me why the other guy posts that I need to cover the basics of C? and then that my code is sloppy? This website is for programmer to become better at understanding code. It is not to criticize how a programmer codes. If you read carefully all the comments you might understand my attitude.

Comment: @Gandaro Also, this a program that I come across, and I thought it was interesting. So next time, you should watch what you posted if you do not want people to come back at you. And please, do not criticize code. This is only an advice for your benefit.

Comment: I don't think you can use this site to become better, if they show code like this. ;-)  And it is impolite, if someone shouts at you like this: !!!  And why should I not criticize code?  Also, if you know what the "and" operator is, you should know what it does...  EOD on my side.

Comment: @Gandaro Woow... It seems that you are not getting the point, right? I am going to repeat it: "So, the point of this question was not if this is sloppy code or not..." You can see it in one of my comments. Let me start with this, you might have better experience with coding than I have and know everything. If you keep reading my first post, I said that I was confused. And to become better in something, you try to solve problems, and if you can not solve certain problems, you just simply asked. We have this saying back in my hometown: "It is wise to ask!"

Comment: @Gandaro So, this is why many people ask questions here TO BECOME BETTER at UNDERSTANDING CODE. I do not know how long you have been programming, but you certainly know that you come across many types of codes. They may be crappy or not, you still need to understand them. Personally, you might be even a better programmer if you understand crappy code, because crappy code is sometimes very difficult to understand, but that does not mean that it is correct to code crappy.

Comment: @Gandaro Ok! Second, you did not answer any of my question that I have asked here (in my last comment and my main question, but anyways) To answer your question "why you should not criticize code?" would be this. Do no criticize code because people might get offended, SPECIALLY if you criticize and do not propose any solutions. Here is another advice, instead of criticizing try to recommend. I think is way better, and you will not get offended if someone like me has the enough... you know what I mean... to tell you what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called the logical AND operator. This will evaluate the logical ANDing result of the two operands. The property of this operator is:

First the left hand side operand is evaluated, if it is TRUE (non zero), then the right hand side operand is evaluated. If it is also true then the whole expression is true, or false otherwise. On the other hand, if the left hand side operand is FALSE, then the right hand side operand is *not evaluated* at all. This can be done because, as one of the operands is false, whatever be the other operand, the expression becomes false. This is known as [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

In your code, if the left hand if `ret` is true, then only the right hand side portion is evaluated, which eventually calls the `fork ()` system call. The return value of the call is ANDed with the current value of `ret`, and reassigned to `ret`.

Basically it works like

```
if (ret == TRUE)
{
  retval = fork ();
  ret = ret && retval;
}
```

Read this:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in  the  parent,  no  child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

Consider the fork tree below. Each tree "node" shows the sequence of executed statement in each individual statement. One work in one line.

```
    (p1)
+--+ret = fork ();
|   printf 1 shows pid
|   && allows         fork (), ret = 1 = pid1 && pid2 
|   printf 2 shows 1    +
|   `if' not entered    |
|   show hello          |
|                       |    (p3)
|                       +--+ ret = 0 = ret && fork () (this is 0 here)
+-----+                      printf 2 shows 0
      |                      `if' is entered
      |                      fork ()
      |                      show hello
      |                            +
      |                            |
      +                            |
     (p2)                          |
    level 1                        +-------+
    print 0 in 1st printf                  |
    && DOES NOT allow fork ()            (p5)
    print 0 in 2st printf             show hello
   `if' entered
    fork () +-----------+
    show hello          |
                        |
                        +
                      (p4)
                    show hello
```

Here what goes in each process.

**p1**
executes `fork ()` once, and has a pid (non-zero) in ret.
prints the pid
short circuit allows to execute fork (). As this is the parent, it returns another pid, which is anded with the previous child pid, which evaluates to 1. Therefore `ret` now contains 1, which is printed in the second printf. as `ret` is 1, `if` is not executes. Hello is printed.

**p2**
Child of p1, so ret has 0. prints 0 in the first printf. Short circuit does not allow `fork ()` call. `if` body is entered, and `fork ()` is called, which makes (p4). Now (p2) proceeds to print Hello.

**p3** 
Child of p1, so `fork ()` return is 0, which is ANDed with ret, and makes it 0 after the assignment. This is spawned after the first printf, so only the second printf shows 0.
`if` is entered, `fork ()` is executed, which makes (p5). Now p4 proceeds to print Hello.

**p4**
starts from `if` body, gets out and prints Hello

**p5**
starts from `if` body, gets out and prints Hello

Above I have tried to express the process spawn tree, and the sequence of works in each process is expressed in each line of the process "node" on the tree. The edges denote spawn, and the edge start at the corresponding fork.

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies a lot!!

Comment: Note what are printed at each level.

Answer (score 6):

In C, the double ampersand `&&` is a short-circuit [logical AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) operation. If you have something like `a && b`, then this will evaluate as follows: it will return true if both `a` and `b` are true, but if `a` is false then `b` will never be executed.

As an added [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

> ```
> int a = 0;
> if (a && myfunc(b)) {
>     do_something();
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, short-circuit evaluation guarantees that myfunc(b) is never called. This is because a evaluates to false. This feature permits two useful programming constructs. Firstly, if the first sub-expression checks whether an expensive computation is needed and the check evaluates to false, one can eliminate expensive computation in the second argument. Secondly, it permits a construct where the first expression guarantees a condition without which the second expression may cause a run-time error.

So your code only calls `fork()` if `ret` is true. `ret` is then assigned either 0 (`ret` is 0) or 1 (both `ret` and `fork()` are true).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! Now it makes sense. It was kind of a dumb question, but I did not see the answer after you showed me. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a logical AND, meaning if `ret` is true (non-zero), AND the result of `fork()` is true (non-zero) assign true to `ret`, else assign false (zero) to `ret`.

Since this operator is [short-cirucuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `fork()` will be called only if `ret` is true.

Comment: Then explain why "the output in the first printf is 0 and the second printf is 1"

Comment: @BlackBear - I will in an hour, have to catch a ride/

Comment: Probably important to note that what it's really trying to do is cause prevent the child from forking again since "Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent process."

Comment: @BlackBear: The ordering of the printf of parent and child cannot be predicted. Without synchronization it may interleave. You can check my answer for the process tree, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's wrong is a misunderstanding of how fork() works.  If you're on UNIX, you need to do "man fork", because according to the one I read:

> DESCRIPTION
>         fork()  creates  a new process by duplicating the calling process.  The
>         new process, referred to as the child, is an  exact  duplicate  of  the
>         calling  process,  referred  to as the parent,

and..

> RETURN VALUE
>         On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
>         0  is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent,
>         no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

I suspect what might be happening is you might be seeing output from multiple forked processes that is only succeeding in confusing you.  What is the exact full output of your program?

This is unlikely to be a short circuit problem because even if the second one fails, at least the first fork should have succeeded, and thus you should get a pid from at least one of the first printfs if that fork succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lazy logical `AND` function. Search for the truth table for `AND` if you need more info on that. It's lazy because if ret is false, `fork()` will not be evaluated since anything ANDed with `false` is always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a short-circuit logical AND. If `ret` is 0, then it will execute the `fork()`. If not, it won't. I can walk through the code for you.

```
//we fork a child process
int ret = fork();

//ret is 0 if we are in the child process, -1 if fork failed
//otherwise ret is the process id of the child process

//because of this, the fork below executes only within the child process
ret = ret && fork(); /* Here is where I am confused*/

//at this point, if we did fork a process (in the child), then ret is 0 in the child
//then we fork again
if(ret == 0) {
    fork();
}
```

So we have our first process, process 1 executing this code. Let's assume all forks are successful (but you should make sure to check this... I think it should be handled within the existing code but it isn't that obvious).

- Process 1 forks, creating a child process with process ID 2.
- ret is now 2 in process 1 and 0 in process 2.
- In process 1, since ret is non-zero, no fork happens.
- In process 2, ret is 0, so we fork a child process with process ID 3.
- Now ret in process 1, 2, and 3 are 2, 3, and 0, respectively.
- Now process 3 will fork a new child.

Answer (score 0):

The first fork, ret - fork(), will result in 3 possible outcomes:

- > 0 => parent gets pid of child
- = 0 => child process
- < 0 => error with fork

The second fork, ret = ret && fork(), will execute the fork() only if ret is nonzero.  This can happen in the parent good case and the parent error case.  The result of this statement can be:

- == 0 => ret was nonzero and fork() is zero.
- != 0 => ret was nonzero and fork() was nonzero.

The third fork, if (ret == 0) { fork() }, will only execute if ret is zero.

So what does all of this mean?  The second fork seems suspect in that the return value from the first fork could be nonzero in the case of a parent success or failure!  I don't know if this was the intended result, but it seems dubious.

The third fork would happen if the first fork return was in the child, the second fork doesn't get executed, but the third does.  The third fork can also get executed if the first fork is in the parent context and the second fork is in the child context.

Someone check this logic as I could never write this kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

In C language, the act of the `&&` operator is so:

1. Calculate the first argument. if it's zero, don't calculate the second argument, and the result is 0.
2. If the first argument isn't zero, calculate the second argument. if it's zero, the answer is 0. else, it's 1.

The function `fork` return 0 to the child process, and another number (the child's pid) to the father, so after your first `fork`, in the father process `ret>0`, and in the child process, `ret==0`. If you uncomment the first `printf`, you will get 0 and another number.

Then, you run your line. In the child, `ret` is 0, so the calculating of the `&&` is stopped before of the fork, and `ret` remains 0. In the father, `ret>0`, so it runs `fork()`, and create another child. In the father process, `fork` return positive number, so `ret` will be 1, and in the second child, `fork` return 0, so `ret` will be 0.
So, if you uncomment only the second `printf`, you will get `0`,`0`,`1` (Maybe in different order).

Then, you do `if (ret==0) fork();`, so the both children (whose `ret` is 0) create new process each. Now, you have totally 5 processes, so the line `Hello world\n` will be printed 5 times.

(It's pretty dangerous to use output functions while messing with `fork` - you have 5 processes that write to the same file without any locking, so you can get results like `HHHHHeeeeellllllllllooooo     wwwwwooooorrrrrlllllddddd\n\n\n\n\n`)

Comment: Yes. That is what I realize after it. Thanks for the explanations. And don't worry with that. The point of this program is to know how many processes this program has. And I thought it should have more than five, and when I tried to debug it I realized that what I was thinking in that line was wrong. That is why I was asking was going on in that particular line. Again thank for you explanation.